# Ternary operator unknown behavior

Tags: java, java-8

I wrote a small programm that takes 3 numbers from console and calculate kind of square.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TheatreSquare {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = scanner.nextInt();
    int m = scanner.nextInt();
    int a = scanner.nextInt();

    long i = n / a + n % a != 0 ? 1 : 0;
    long j = m / a + m % a != 0 ? 1 : 0;

    System.out.println(i);
    System.out.println(j);
    System.out.println((long)i*j);
}
}
```

The problem I faced during testing was the following - when you enter numbers:
1000000000
1000000000
1

it returns:
1
1
1

while it's supposed to return 
1000000000
1000000000
1000000000000000000

If you cover both ternary operator with parentheses the result will be correct. But how does it affect it? As far as I know order of execution should be the same, there is no overflow here. So why does it work like this?

Comment: If the parentheses changes the outcome, then the order of execution is obviously not the same as without. It's not a smart idea to write out code like that. You can assume the wrong order of execution just like you did now, and the code is totally unreadable. Don't write bad code.

Comment: Do you mean `(n/a + n%a != 0) ? 1 : 0` ? Or do you mean `n/a + (n%a != 0 ? 1 : 0)` ? They obviously have different results.

Comment: I mean: 
long i = n / a + (n % a != 0 ? 1 : 0);
long j = m / a + (m % a != 0 ? 1 : 0);
Do they? Ternary has the lowest precedence, it anyway should be executed at the very last moment.

Answer (score 2):

Check the operator precedence order table [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) : the ternary operator appears in the last places, after the (in)equality operator or the arithmetic operators, so without parenthesis you're going to evaluate `n / a + n % a != 0` first, then evaluate `result ? 1 : 0`, then assign that to your variable.

If that's not to your taste, add parenthesis.

Even if that's what you wanted, adding parenthesis would greatly improve readability.